# how to change adsense payee name without losing my earnings

Tags: adsense

due to a spelling error, i missed spelling my company's payee name, i googled if i can change it and i've found that my country (Morocco) is in the liste of the countries that can't change the payee name, and the only way to do that is to disable my account and send a new application.
my question is the following: is there another way to change my payee name ? if not, will i keep my earnings if i disable my account and send a new application with the same gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

You can change payee name in Google adsense's new payment setting options.

Check here.. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2498454?hl=en&ref_topic=1727187

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the payee name, unless you are correcting a minor error like a typo.